# Why is my modal system not working at all?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to open the modal in specific conditions.

The system needs to:

- Open the modal in specific conditions.
- Open the correct modal in specific conditions.

There are no error messages, making it harder to track down.

I've tried running `modalSys()` directly from the console to no avail.

```js
function modalSys() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem("data") === undefined) {
      console.log("This user has no data.")
      let modal = document.getElementById("nodata");
      modal.style.display = "block";
    };
  } else {
    console.error("This browser does not support LocalStorage.");
    let modal = document.getElementById("nostore");
    modal.style.display = "block";
  };
};
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Questrial&display=swap');
div {
  background-color: #888888;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Questrial;
}

.selectoff {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

.head {
  height: 75px;
}

#imgh {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#h1h {
  display: inline-block;
}

h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+p {
  color: white;
  font-family: Questrial;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.lhalf {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}

.rhalf {
  float: right;
  width: 75%;
}

button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: Questrial;
  background-color: red;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="scripting.js"></script>
  <header>
    <div class="selectoff head">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Favicon/Logo" id="imgh">
      <h1 id="h1h">example</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="nodata" class="modal">
    <span>&times;</span>
    <h1>Uh oh!</h1>
    <p>It looks like you don't have any data.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="nostore" class="modal">
    <span>&times;</span>
    <h1>Uh oh!</h1>
    <p>This browser does not support LocalStorage.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Off topic: I'm guessing that `h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+p {}` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. When is the function _supposed_ to run? Where does `Storage` come from?

Comment: I tested your code in jsfiddle and seems to work

Comment: @isherwood I got that code from w3schools and it's supposed to run when the HTML page loads, and ```h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+p {}``` is me trying to do less work on CSS.

Comment: @imvain2 The code does not work when I tried it in jsfiddle, what do you mean?

Comment: That CSS selector looks for _siblings_ in that arrangement. I don't see that in this code example, and I doubt it'll ever occur. Perhaps you meant to use commas instead of pluses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things I can think of:

1. You nowhere seem to call the `modalSys()` function.
2. You need to include the JavaScript file, at the end of the `body`. If you include it at the beginning, where the elements are not loaded, then it will throw error.

```js
function modalSys() {
  if (false) { //changed to false for testing purposes
    if (localStorage.getItem("data") === undefined) {
      console.log("This user has no data.")
      let modal = document.getElementById("nodata");
      modal.style.display = "block";
    };
  } else {
    console.log("This browser does not support LocalStorage.");
    let modal = document.getElementById("nostore");
    modal.style.display = "block";
  };
};

modalSys()
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Questrial&display=swap');
div {
  background-color: #888888;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Questrial;
}

.selectoff {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

.head {
  height: 75px;
}

#imgh {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#h1h {
  display: inline-block;
}

h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+p {
  color: white;
  font-family: Questrial;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.lhalf {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}

.rhalf {
  float: right;
  width: 75%;
}

button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: Questrial;
  background-color: red;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="selectoff head">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Favicon/Logo" id="imgh">
      <h1 id="h1h">example</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="nodata" class="modal">
    <span>&times;</span>
    <h1>Uh oh!</h1>
    <p>It looks like you don't have any data.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="nostore" class="modal">
    <span>&times;</span>
    <h1>Uh oh!</h1>
    <p>This browser does not support LocalStorage.</p>
  </div>
  <script src="scripting.js"></script>
</body>
```